# Mongoose : using promises as parameters for other functions

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise, async.js

I am trying to get a good understanding of how to work with promises, mostly because I want to query data and then use that data to query other data

I have this Schema :

```
var serviceSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
});
```

And this method on it :

```
serviceSchema.statics.getIdByName = function getIdByName (serviceName) {

this.findOne({name :serviceName }).exec(function(err, service){
    if(err) console.log(err)

    return service._id

})
}
```

In my code I would like to do something like :

```
var service_id = Service.getIdByName("facebook")
otherSchema.findOne({service : service_id}).exec(...)
```

but service_id is a promise so the query isn't right, I don't want to be in callback hell and calling models inside of callbacks etc
I have tried async with something like

```
async.series([getVariables], function(err, results){
otherSchema.findOne({service : service_id}).exec(...)})
```

Where getVariables is :

```
function getVariables(callback1) {
if(service_id!=undefined) {
    callback1(serviceID)
}}
```

Any help on how to achieve this is more than welcome!
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is actually using async/await and and do 
var x = await Model.findOne().exec()

or any function that returns a promise, then you can use x anywhere in the code

Answer (score 2):

try this `exec()` returns promise.

```
serviceSchema.statics.getIdByName = function getIdByName(serviceName) {
    return this.findOne({
        name: serviceName
    }).exec();
}
```

Call getIdByName function

```
Service.getIdByName("facebook").then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, this doesnt solve my problem because getIdByName is now only a findOne function and I can access the service's id only inside the 'then' where i would like to access it outside, stored in a variable i can pass as parameter to an other query
does that mean i can only do that inside the 'then' ? isnt that callback hell, because in fact i have to get many ids before doing the query

Comment: @mtths It'll not create callback hell because you can create the chain of promises, not callback hell.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: heres a more readable version : 
Service.findOne({name : 'JollyClick'}).then(function(service){
 
var service_id = service._id 
return Data.findOne({name : "Objectifs"}).exec() })

.then(function(data){ 

var objectifsID = data._id 
return Data.findOne({name : 'Personnalité'}).exec() }).

then(function(data2){

var personnaliteID = data2._id 
DataUse.create({service : service_id, user : service_id, data : dataTypesIds}, function(err, datause){ }) 

cant access service_id when i want to create my document

Comment: declare service_id outside `.then` and assign value inside `.then`.  `var service_id;
Service.findOne({
        name: 'JollyClick'
    }).then(function (service) {
        service_id; = service._id
        return Data.findOne({
            name: "Objectifs"
        }).exec();
    })`

Comment: ive been trying your solution, it works for the first 2 then but in the third it says that the result of the previous one is undefined (i tried a simple query, it does return the right document)
can you see something wrong?

Comment: Service.findOne({name : 'JollyClick'}).exec().then(function(service){
    service_id = service._id;
    return Data.findOne({name : 'Objectifs'}).exec();
}).then(function(data){
    objectifsID = data._id;
    dataTypesIds.push(objectifsID);
    return Data.findOne({name : 'Personnalite'}).exec()
})

Comment: .then(function(data2){

    personnaliteID = data2._id;
    dataTypesIds.push(personnaliteID);
    return Purpose.findOne({name : 'Newsfeed'}).exec();
}).then(function(purpose){
        console.log('final')
    newsfeedID = purpose._id;
    DataUse.create({service : service_id, user : service_id, data : dataTypesIds, purpose : newsfeedID, description : "Pour vous présenter les contenus les plus adaptés dans votre fil d'actualité"}, function(err, datause){
        if(err) console.log(err)
        
        
    })
})

Comment: add `.catch` and check what are you getting

Comment: the only error im getting is that data2 is undefined, as i said a simple query returns the right document